# Which scholars deny possession of humans by jinn?

Tags: jinn, islamic-scholar

Which scholars deny possession of humans by jinn?
I guess [ibn hazm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Hazm) was one of them. Tareq Al-Suwaidan is also one of those who are against possesision by jinn.

**Which more (old and nowday) scholars deny the possession of humans by jinn? How small is the group that holds this view (and how is this number concluded)?**

I am not interested about the opinions about which belief is the right one. That is another question that can be found [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/822/can-jinns-possess-humans).

Comment: Well, that's kind of research work, that i am afraid if there is that kind of researcher here. anyway, best of luck. and i hope we see a good answer here, and meanwhile, read something at http://www.islamicboard.com/aqeedah/134283614-reality-jinn-possession.html

Comment: Yeah, I know. I decided to make a try anyway. Thanks!

Comment: jakumullah khair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a list of scholars that may end up short as salafi pretend having consensus on the matter ;):

> Shaykh al-Islam Ibn Taymiyah (may Allah have mercy on him) said:
>
> The fact that a jinni **may enter the body of a human is proven by the consensus of the imams of Ahl al-Sunnah wa’l-Jama’ah** (the larger body of Muslims who are upon the prophetic traditions). Allah says (interpretation of the meaning):
>
> “Those who eat riba [usury] will not stand (on the Day of Resurrection) except like the standing of a person beaten by shaytan leading him to insanity.” ([2:275](http://legacy.quran.com/2/275)) (from [this fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/73412))

So there's ibn Hazm, maybe others and from the more modern scholars there are Sheikh Muhammad al-Ghazaly and Sheikh Rashid Reda (author of Tafsir al-Manar) so far ... and ibn Amin the author (who seems to me a fan of the dhahiri school in general and ibn Hazm in special and a hater of the Maliki school in particular) of my major reference discussing the proofs for those who say that Satan or Jinn can go beyond whispering to humans.

According to [this thread](http://www.almeshkat.net/vb/showthread.php?t=108502) counting other scholars who deny possesion of human by jinn i can add those:

> وذهب الى هذا القول (جمال الدين الأفغاني - محمد عبده - ابو حامد الغزالي – الجبائي من المعتزلة – والقفال من الشافعية – والبيضاوي من الشافعية – والفخر الرازي – والقاضي أبو يعلى – وعبد الجبار الهمداني من المعتزلة – والشيخ محمود شلتوت – الشيخ المراغي – والشيخ جاد الحق – وغيرهم)

Modern scholars: [Jamal ad-Din al-Afhgani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jam%C4%81l_al-D%C4%ABn_al-Afgh%C4%81n%C4%AB), [Muhammad 'Abduh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_Abduh), Sheikh [Muhammad Shaltot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahmud_Shaltut), Sheikh [Jad al-Haqq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gad_al-Haq), Sheikh [al-Muraghi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mustafa_Al-Maraghi).
Ancient scholars: Abu Hamid al-Ghazali, the mu'tazilah like al-Jibaa'i and abduljabbar al-Hamdani, the shafi'i scholars al-Qaffal and al-Baydawi, al-Fakhr ar-Razi, al-Qadi abu Ya'ala.

Note that while reading this thread I would also add a-Tahar Benachour (and others) as he said that satan has no infulence on the children of Adam unless through whispering as it is quoted and affirmed from many verses of the Quran (my own translation of the quote)

> فإن الشيطان لا تأثير له في بني آدم بغير الوسوسة كما هو مقرر من مكرر آيات القرآن

I also add Sheikh a-Sha'rawy الشعراوي because of his statement about verse 2:275 [here](http://www.al-eman.com/%D8%AA%D9%81%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%B1%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B4%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%88%D9%8A/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%82%D8%B1%D8%A9/t33&s2&p22?d-2619820-p=91):

> ويقول الحق: {الذي يَتَخَبَّطُهُ الشيطان مِنَ المس} الشيطان قلنا: إنه العاصي من الجن، وقلنا: إن ربنا سبحانه وتعالى حكى لنا كثيرا أن الشياطين لهم التصاق واتصال بكثير من الإنس: {وَأَنَّهُ كَانَ رِجَالٌ مِّنَ الإنس يَعُوذُونَ بِرِجَالٍ مِّنَ الجن فَزَادُوهُمْ رَهَقاً} [الجن: 6].
>   و{لاَ يَقُومُونَ إِلاَّ كَمَا يَقُومُ الذي يَتَخَبَّطُهُ الشيطان مِنَ المس} فكأن الشيطان قد مس التكوين الإنساني مساً أفسد استقامة ملكاته، فالتكوين الإنساني له استقامة ملكات مع بعضها البعض؛ فكل حركة لها استقامة، فإذا ما مسّه الشيطان فسد تآزر الملكات، فملكاته النفسية تكون غير مستقيمة وغير منسجمة مع بعضها البعض، فتكون حركته غير رتيبة وغير منطقية

He also denies it in [this interview 1:45](https://youtu.be/ybkfpF0GNYs?t=7m6s) and denies that human can control Jinn to serve them.

And the mufassir of the mua'tazilah school Imam az-Zamakhshari who say in his tafsir of 2:275 that "beeing beaten by satan" was something the Arabs used to pretend if somebody acted in a weird manner ... (as quoted in the thread)

> **إلا كما يقوم الذي يتخبطه الشيطان** أي: المصروع، وتخبط الشيطان من زعمات العرب، يزعمون أن الشيطان يخبط الإنسان فيصرع، والخبط الضرب على غير استواء كخبط العشواء، فورد على ما كانوا يعتقدون، والمس: الجنون، ورجل ممسوس، وهذا أيضا من زعماتهم، وأن الجني يمسه فيختلط عقله، وكذلك جن الرجل معناه: ضربته الجن، ورأيتهم لهم في الجن قصص وأخبار وعجائب، وإنكار ذلك عندهم كإنكار المشاهدات.

which shows that he doesn't believe this being true!

---

P.S.:I've deleted my former answer and posted it as an answer on [Can Jinns possess humans?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/822/can-jinns-possess-humans)

Comment: Thanks for your earlier answer. As Zia Ul Rehman Mughal said, this is a kind of research work and might be hard to find anyone holding that information in this forum. +1 for trying and for rashid reda!

Comment: @Kilise I'm not deep into that I believe in Jinn as they are quoted in the Quran anything supernatural calls my skepticism!

Comment: Could you help me verify whether sharawi (الشعراوي) denies possession of humans by jinn or not?

Comment: He is being asked the question here: https://youtu.be/ybkfpF0GNYs?t=7m6s but i really dont understand (or hear) what he answers.

Comment: @Kilise I edited my answer. Maybe one should check said Qutub and al-Madudi too but both don't even discuss the statement about being beaten by satan in verse 2:275!

Comment: Great! I am accepting your answer, since it seems we are coming some where with the list. If you come up with more scholars now or in the future don't hesitate to add them here.